# sqlAlchemy schema - Multiple optional columns

Tags: sql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have an app built on Flask, using sqlalchemy as an ORM, it will have books with an upvote system based on multiple languages as columns, so if a book has been translated to 20 languages, each language will have its own voting score.

Some books could have 30 languages available and some only one.

- Is it possible to have multiple columns being optional?
- Any pointers to how I should tackle this?

I am fairly new to sql. So I'm not sure how to do proper research on this. I was following Miguel Grinberg's Micro blog tutorial and while his followers system is somewhat similar, I'm not sure how to extend it to my case. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's many possible ways to do this.

I would probably do something like:

Have model/table `books`.
Have model/table `languages`.
Have model/table `book_in_language`, which has some rating (which is probably aggregated from `user_book_in_language_rating` table.